# IllegalAccessException when accessing EJB separated interfaces

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, ejb

My EJB project has below structure and packaged using maven. It has the ejb packaged in the core.jar file. Remote lookup has been made possible by moving all interfaces and POJO's in a separate project packaged as a jar *(core-common.jar)*, which is then added to web module as dependencies, to enable it use them for remote EJB calls.

```
├── core.jar
├── app_war
│   ├── META-INF
│   └── WEB-INF       
├── lib
    └──core-common.jar
```

When I deploy my application, I end up with `IllegalAccessException - access denied` when core tries to instantiate any of the POJO's and in the `core-common.jar`. None of the POJO's or classes have private method or constructors. This has left me baffled.

Also let me point out that, In the past these POJO's has its constructors `protected`, and after re-factoring it to tier the POJO's and the interfaces, I decided to make all public.

Does anyone know what might be causing this Illegal access after the re-factoring? the application is deployed on Glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of pain and web digging without any joy, I decided to filter the classes from the `core-common.jar` to package with `core`. This fixed it.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>resource-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeGroupIds>net.proj-alkaline</includeGroupIds>
                        <includeArtifactIds>core-common</includeArtifactIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>**/*</includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```